# Split string on first occurrence of separator only

Tags: python, regex, string

The POS tagger that I use processes the following string

```
3+2
```

as shown below.

```
3/num++/sign+2/num
```

I'd like to split this result as follows using python.

```
['3/num', '+/sign', '2/num']
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show us your code ? what have you tried sofar ? where does it go wrong ? ... thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) -

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'(?<!\+)\+', '3/num++/sign+2/num')
['3/num', '+/sign', '2/num']
```

The regex pattern will split on a `+` sign as long as no other `+` precedes it.

```
(?<!   # negative lookbehind
\+     # plus sign
)     
\+     # plus sign
```

Note that lookbehinds (in general) do not support varying length patterns.

Comment: It seems some downvoter want to think I downvote your solutions. But he is wrong ;) Because our agreement ;)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ This is the perfect answer. I also wanted to solve it using re.split(), but I couldn't find a way. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part I believe is the double `+` sign. You can replace the signs with special characters and get it done.

This should work,

```
st = '3/num++/sign+2/num'

st = st.replace('++', '@$')
st = st.replace('+', '@')
st = st.replace('$', '+')

print (st.split('@'))
```

One issue with this is that, your original string cannot contain those special characters `@` & `$`. So you will need to carefully choose them for your use case.

**Edit**: This answer is naive. The one with regex is better
That is, as pointed out by COLDSPEED, you should use the following regex approach with lookbehind,

```
import re
print re.split(r'(?<!\+)\+', '3/num++/sign+2/num')
```

Comment: This is extremely tedious and roundabout, not to mention the danger with using an arbitrarily chosen character as a delimiter.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I agree. Your answer is better

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Although the ask was to use regex, here is an example on how to do this with standard `.split()`:

```
my_string = '3/num++/sign+2/num'

my_list = []
result = []

# enumerate over the split string
for e in my_string.split('/'):
    if '+' in e:
        if '++' in e:
            #split element on double + and add in + as well 
            my_list.append(e.split('++')[0])
            my_list.append('+')
        else:
            #split element on single +
            my_list.extend(e.split('+'))
    else:
        #add element
        my_list.append(e)

# at this point my_list contains
# ['3', 'num', '+', 'sign', '2', 'num']

# enumerate on the list, steps of 2
for i in range(0, len(my_list), 2):
    #add result 
    result.append(my_list[i] + '/' + my_list[i+1])

print('result', result)

# result returns
# ['3/num', '+/sign', '2/num']
```